# Automatically Unique Id generate at all html tag in vue cli

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I have a Vue project where more than 100 vue file with lot of html(I use vuetify for material design) code.

Now, all vue files need to generate unique id at all html tag. For this problem, I implemented a solution. That is:

```
mounted() {
    let tags = document.querySelectorAll( "div, span"); 
    //here I will add more html tag. Now div and span use for testing purpose
    for (let i = 0; i<tags.length; i++) {
       if (!tags[i].getAttribute('id')) {
          let id_value = `${this.$route.meta.page_id}-tmtw-0${i}`;
          tags[i].setAttribute('id', id_value);
       }
    }
},
```

This code give me a proper solution at my existing html tag. Problem is when I add a new vuetify tag (like: `v-textfield`), then automatically generate the code:

```
<div data-v-a52abf8c="" class="tm-login-input-join"><div data-v-a52abf8c="" class="v-input tm-input-text-field-login v-input--has-state v-input--dense theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--single-line v-text-field--solo v-text-field--solo-flat v-text-field--is-booted v-text-field--enclosed v-text-field--placeholder error--text"><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-input__slot"><div class="v-input__prepend-inner"><div class="v-input__icon v-input__icon--prepend-inner"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-email-outline theme--light error--text"></i></div></div><div class="v-text-field__slot"><input required="required" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" id="email" placeholder="Type your Email" type="text"></div></div><div class="v-text-field__details"><div class="v-messages theme--light error--text" role="alert"><div class="v-messages__wrapper"><div class="v-messages__message">E-mail is required</div></div></div></div></div></div><form data-v-a52abf8c="" novalidate="novalidate" class="v-form tm-login-form"><button data-v-a52abf8c="" type="button" class="tm-button-next v-btn v-btn--contained theme--dark v-size--default"><span class="v-btn__content"><i data-v-a52abf8c="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-play theme--dark white--text"></i></span></button></form></div>
```

So next time at mounted hook, the id regenerates with the new tags. That's for existing id is changed.

**My question is: how can solve this issue for vuetify in vue js?**

Comment: why do you need IDs?

Comment: The wording is unclear. If you mean that elements are created after mounted hook and not handed, then yes, it's possible. This is a reason to not do a thing you do. A component should support this behaviour explicitly. This can probably solved by applying mounted to all nested components via global mixin, yet elements that are created with raw DOM calls won't be handled still. It's possible that you have XY problem and there may be no need to do what you try to do.

Comment: @GeorgiyBukharov id need for custom tooltip. An admin will inspect any html tag and the get id value and this value inserted in input form from admin panel and this specific html tag shows an hover(this functionality already done). But now need all html tag's id.

Comment: @omorfaruk, do you really need to add it to EVERY tag?

Comment: @GeorgiyBukharov,  yes. Now my maximum code is done. After completing my code, I will answer that.